# Movie for kids about a group of 4 kids getting "Power Ranger" powers

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find a live-action movie that I watched in the late 1990s or early 2000s, probably between 1999 and 2002.  It was in French, but looked like an American movie.  I watched it on VHS.

The story follows a group of 4 kids (3 boys - 1 girl?) that entered a scary old man's house. (I think there was a dog guarding the main door.)
The old man turned out to be a good person and offered the kids to get power-ranger-like transformation. I remember that:

- one of the kids got the "green dragon" power
- one of the kids got the "red lion" power
- one might have got the "blue eagle" (not sure)
- might have been a "pink/yellow panthera/tiger" (really not sure)

They had to face a bad guy at some point and defeated him using a triangular-shaped beam that came out of their power ranger helmet or chest armor.

There might be a fight scene in a supermarket.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this live-action or animated?  In English?  Where did you see it?

Comment: Hi, thank you. Live-action, in French (but looked like an American movie), I watched it on a VHS when I was ~5-8 y.o (born in 1994)
(should I add those pieces of information as an Edit on the main post?)

Comment: “There might be a fight scene in a supermarket” — gosh I hope there is.

Comment: @Kevin-H2R Yes, should always add additional information into the main post.  (I've done that for you.)  Comments can be cleaned up, and we don't want to lose useful information.  Even though you have your answer, the more details in the question the more useful it can be for someone else looking for the same movie.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the character powers, this is likely [*Super Ranger Kids*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0381631) (1997).  The credits list:

- Zacky / Super Ranger 'Red Lion'
- Tom / Super Ranger 'Green Dragon'
- Willy / Super Ranger 'Blue Eagle'
- Tiny / Super Ranger 'Yellow Tiger'
- Kim / Super Ranger 'Pink Panther'

I haven't found a plot summary yet, but [Wikipedia notes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Ranger_Kids):

> ***Super Ranger Kids*** is a Filipino superhero film directed by Rogelio Salvador. Released in 1997, the film is a pastiche of the American television series *Mighty Morphin Power Rangers*, the first *Power Rangers* series, and, by extension, the Japanese Super Sentai series *Kyōryū Sentai Zyuranger*, which formed the basis for *Mighty Morphin*.

It notes that the primary difference from *Power Rangers* is that the Rangers are younger, 10-12 year old, than the counterpart series.